# How multi_match search in elastic on main object and nested array of objects?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I'm using **elastic-search v7** and I have mapped object like below.
Items its nested array of objects.

My problem is, when I try search by **multi_match** items fields, its not working like I expect, result is empty. But when I try to search with query and boolean, its finds my document.

I don't correct understand what a different there, how I understand is **query_search** its exact matches using for filter and aggregation  of data, and **multi_match** for full text search and autocomplete , right?

**And how to find documents searching in root fields and nested fields?**

```
{
  "orders" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "amazonOrderId" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "carrierCode" : {
          "type" : "text"
        },
        "carrierName" : {
          "type" : "text"
        },
        "id" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "items" : {
          "type" : "nested",
          "properties" : {
            "amazonItemId" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "amazonPrice" : {
              "type" : "integer"
            },
            "amazonQuantity" : {
              "type" : "integer"
            },
            "amazonSku" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "graingerItem" : {
              "type" : "nested"
            },
            "graingerOrderId" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "graingerPrice" : {
              "type" : "integer"
            },
            "graingerShipDate" : {
              "type" : "date"
            },
            "graingerShipMethod" : {
              "type" : "short"
            },
            "graingerTrackingNumber" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "graingerWebNumber" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "id" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
     }
   }
 }
}
```

**multi_match request**

```
GET orders/_search
{
  "query":{
    "multi_match" : {
      "query": "4.48 - 1 pack - 4.48",
      "fields": [
          "items.amazonSku",
          "carrierCode",
          "recipientName"
        ]
    }
  }
}
```

Debugging by _explain api returns me that description

```
"explanation" : {
    "value" : 0.0,
    "description" : "Failure to meet condition(s) of required/prohibited clause(s)",
    "details" : [
      {
        "value" : 0.0,
        "description" : "no match on required clause (items.amazonSku:4.48 - 1 pack - 4.48)",
        "details" : [
          {
            "value" : 0.0,
            "description" : "no matching term",
            "details" : [ ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "value" : 0.0,
        "description" : "match on required clause, product of:",
        "details" : [
          {
            "value" : 0.0,
            "description" : "# clause",
            "details" : [ ]
          },
          {
            "value" : 1.0,
            "description" : "DocValuesFieldExistsQuery [field=_primary_term]",
            "details" : [ ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Query search

```
GET orders/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "items",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            { "match": { "items.amazonSku": "4.48 - 1 pack - 4.48"}}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are querying on nested field `items`, you need to include the [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) param in your query so that it searches for the nested field object

Modify your search as

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "items",
      "query": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": "4.48 - 1 pack - 4.48",
          "fields": [
            "items.amazonSku"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: And if I understand , we also may add before nested query for main object, if we need search on main object and nested fields, that right?

Comment: yes @Drop you can combine both nested and non-nested queries. And, please don't forget to upvote and accept the answer, if it helped you resolve your issue :)

Comment: its srange, but its not worked for me win nested and root object, its started working after when I added for nested mapping include_in_root

Comment: @Drop if the answer helped you resolve your issue, then please don't forget to upvote and accept the answer 