# Does Elasticsearch support nested or object fields in MultiMatch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have some object field named "FullTitleFts". It has field "text" inside. This query works fine (and returns some entries):

```
GET index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "fullTitleFts.text": "Ivan"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But this query returns nothing:

```
GET index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "Ivan",
            "fields": [
              "fullTitleFts.text"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Mapping of the field:

```
"fullTitleFts": {
    "copy_to": [
        "text"
    ],
    "type": "keyword",
    "fields": {
        "text": {
            "analyzer": "analyzer",
            "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets_payloads",
            "type": "text"
        }
    }
}


"analyzer": {
    "filter": [
        "lowercase",
        "hypocorisms",
        "protect_kw"
    ],
    "char_filter": [
        "replace_char_filter",
        "e_char_filter"
    ],
    "expand": "true",
    "type": "custom",
    "tokenizer": "standard"
}
```

**e_char_filter** is for replacing Cyrillic char "ё" to "е", **replace_char_filter** is for removing "�" from text. **protect_kw** is keyword_marker for some Russian unions. **hypocorisms** is synonym_graph for making another forms of names.

Example of analyzer output:

```
GET index/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "analyzer",
  "text":     "Алёна�"
}

{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "аленка",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 5,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "аленушка",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 5,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "алена",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 5,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    }
  ]
}
```

I've also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66611750/how-multi-match-search-in-elastic-on-main-object-and-nested-array-of-objects/66611927#66611927). And it seems that the answer didn't really work - author had to add "include_in_root" option in mapping. So i wondering if multi match supports nested or object fields at all. I am also can't find anything about it in docs.

Comment: can you please put your etire mapping which will show defination of `analyzer` as well.

Comment: as per your index mapping, your `fullTitleFts` field is define as [multi-field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) and not as nested or object field.

Comment: I've added the analyzer definition but since it works in simple match query i don't see why it could be different for multi_match. But how do i query the multi-field? It seems to work in match just like in object fields.

Comment: You are doing in right way for query multi-field. I have index document with same text able to get result using both match and multi-match query. can you please post entire index mapping with analyzer and tokenizer as well as filter defination. it will be great helpful.

Comment: It's quite hard to provide a full definition since there is big config files for some of it. Will it help to show an output of analyzer? I've added it to the question. And i can't query any multi-field in my index in multi-match. I am using Elastic 6.8 if it matters.

Comment: Oh i found out the reason, i was using the wrong index. Sorry for misleading. I'll vote for closing

Comment: great to hear about it. i have posted same explanation as answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have provided index mapping, your field is defined as [multi-field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html#_multi_fields_with_multiple_analyzers) and not as nested or object field. So both `match` and `multi_match` should work without providing `path`. you can just use field name as `fullTitleFts.text` when need to search on text type and `fullTitleFts` when need to search on keyword type.